# running a multi touch application in a non mobile browser

Tags: html, multi-touch

I am working on an app that requires multi-touch on a windows tablet. We were hoping to use HTML 5 instead of silverlight however we found out that multi-touch is only available in HTML 5 on mobile browsers and since we are using a windows tablet, it runs windows 7. Is there any way to get multi-touch for HTML 5 working on a non mobile browser or some other way to run muti-touch?

Answer (score 0):

This might work...  https://github.com/borismus/MagicTouch